# Filter generated by a collection of basic neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

Exercise:

Let $x$ be an element of a topological space $X$, and let $B_x$ be a collection of basic neighborhoods of $x$. Prove that the filter on $X$ generated by $B_x$ is the collection of neighborhoods of $x$.

> Proof: First we want to show that $B_x$ is non empty.
>
> Since $x$ is an element of $U$ for all $U \in B_x$ , $B_x$ is non empty.
>
> Next we want to show that if $U \in B_x$ with $U \subseteq V$, then $V \in B_x$.
>
> Let $U \subseteq V$ be an element of $B_x$. Since $U \in B_x$, $x$ is an element of $U \subseteq V$. Hence $x \in V$ and thus $V \in B_x$.
>
> Lastly we will show that for $U, V \in B_x$, $U \cap V \in B_x$.
>
> If $U$ and $V$ are elements of $B_x$,  then x is an element of $U$ and $V$. Hence $x \in U \cap V$ and thus $U \cap V \in B_x$.
>
> Therefore $B_x$ is a filter on X.

Is this a sufficient proof?

Comment: You want $\mathcal{B}_x$ be a local base of neighbourhoods of $x$ not just *any* subcollection of them. And do you take neighbourhood in the liberal sense: any set that contains an open set that contains $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot show that $B_x$ is non-empty: that should have been part of the hypothesis. The specific problem with the argument that you used is that the fact that $x\in U$ for all $U\in B_x$ does not imply that $B_x\ne\varnothing$. If $B_x=\varnothing$, then it is vacuously true that if $U\in B_x$, then $x\in U$: there is no $U\in B_x$, so there is certainly no $U\in B_x$ such that $x\notin U$.

You are trying to prove the wrong thing, something that in general simply isn’t true: a local nbhd base $B_x$ at $x$ is **not** in general a filter. It is not in general true that if $U\in B_x$, and $U\subseteq V$, then $V\in B_x$. Suppose, for instance, that $X$ is the real line with the usual topology, $x=0$, and

$$B_0=\{(-q,q):q\in\Bbb Q^+\}\,;$$

$B_0$ is a local base at $0$. $(-1,1)\in B_0$, and $(-1,1)\subseteq(-\pi,\pi)$, but $(\pi,\pi)\notin B_x$, since $\pi$ is not rational. This $B_0$ is not a filter.

The filter in this question is the one *generated* by $B_x$, which in general is a superset of $B_x$. If $\mathscr{F}$ is the filter generated by $B_x$, and $\mathscr{N}$ is the collection of all nbhds of $x$, you need to show that $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{N}$. Thus, you need to know what the filter generated by $B_x$ is. Let

$$\mathscr{F}_0=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{A}:\mathscr{A}\text{ is a finite subset of }B_x\right\}\,,$$

and let $\mathscr{F}=\{N\subseteq X:\exists A\in\mathscr{F}_0(A\subseteq N)\}$; by definition $\mathscr{F}$ is the filter generated by $B_x$, **provided** that $\mathscr{F}$ actually **is** a filter. In words, a subset $N$ of $X$ belongs to $\mathscr{F}$ if and only if $N$ contains the intersection of finitely many members of $B_x$.

To show that $\mathscr{F}$ is a filter on $X$, you have to check that $\varnothing\notin\mathscr{F}$, that if $N\in\mathscr{F}$ and $N\subseteq M$, then $M\in\mathscr{F}$, and that if $M,N\in\mathscr{F}$, then $M\cap N\in\mathscr{F}$. The second of these follows *very* easily from the definition of $\mathscr{F}$ from $\mathscr{F}_0$; for the first and third you will need to use the hypothesis that $B_x$ is a local nbhd base at $x$.

To prove that $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{N}$, you need to do two things.

- You need to show that if $N$ is any nbhd of $x$, there is a finite $\mathscr{A}\subseteq B_x$ such that $\bigcap\mathscr{A}\subseteq N$; this will show that $N\in\mathscr{F}$ and hence that $\mathscr{N}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$.
- You need to show that if $N\in\mathscr{F}$, then $N$ is a nbhd of $x$, meaning that there is a $V\in B_x$ such that $V\subseteq N$. This will show that $\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{N}$.

Comment: Finally we want to show that $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{N}_{x}$, where $\mathscr{N}$ is the neighborhood system of x. We will do this by first showing $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathscr{N}_{x}$, then $\mathscr{N}_{x} \subseteq \mathscr{F}$. 
Let $N$ be an element of $\mathscr{F}$, then $N$ contains some $V$ in $B_{x}$ such that $N \supseteq V$. Since $V \in B_{x}$, $V$ contains $x$, thus $x$ is an element of $N$ which implies $N$ is a neighborhood of x. Hence $N \in \mathscr{N}_{x}$. Therefore $\mathscr{F}$ is contained in $\mathscr{N}_{x}$.

Comment: Now let $N$ be any neighborhood of x, i.e. $N \in \mathscr{N}_{x}$.
Since $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ it contains an open set $V$ around $x$. Thus $V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. So  $V \in B_{x}$ and $V \subseteq N$. Then by definition of $\mathscr{F}$, $N \in \mathscr{F}$.
Thus $\mathscr{N}_{x} \subseteq \mathscr{F}$. 
Therefore $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{N}_{x}$.

Comment: I know this is not exactly how you set it up for me, but does this work for the last part? I couldn't quite figure out the way you were trying to explain it for me.

Comment: @Kim: The first part is okay, but the second needs a little work. $B_x$ is a local nbhd base at $x$, but it definitely need not be all of $\mathscr{N}$, so you cannot conclude that $V\in B_x$. What you **can** conclude is that $V$ **contains** a member of $B_x$. \\ I wrote that first bullet point to match the definition of $\mathscr{F}$, which I gave in its general form: what I did is how you close a collection of sets under taking finite intersections and supersets. ...

Comment: ... In this case, in which we’re starting with a local base, it’s enough to close under supersets: you can show that defining $\mathscr{F}$ as $$\{N\subseteq X:\exists A\in B_x\,(A\subseteq N)\}$$ would have resulted in the same family.

Comment: Now let $N$ be any neighborhood of x, i.e. $N \in \mathscr{N}_{x}$.
Since $N$ is a neighborhood of $x$ it contains an open set $V$ around $x$. Thus $V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. So $V$ contains some $U \in B_{x}$ thus $U \subseteq V \subseteq N$. Hence $N$ contains a set in $B_x$. Then by definition of $\mathscr{F}$, $N \in \mathscr{F}$.
Thus $\mathscr{N}_{x} \subseteq \mathscr{F}$. 
Therefore $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{N}_{x}$.

Comment: Does that fix it. Sorry I should've included the way I defined $\mathscr{F}$. $$\mathscr{F}=\{V \subseteq X | V \supseteq U \text{ for some } U \subseteq B_{x}\}$$

Comment: @Kim: Yes, that’s fine now.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Kim: You’re very welcome.